# Remove inner box of button

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, button

I already got rid of the border of the button, by setting the borderSize to 0. Unfortunately, this annoying green line still appears. How do I also get rid of this inner board (shown in green)?

The button is already set to Flat.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set the `FlatStyle` property to `Flat`: I tested changing back color and it works fine on Windows10 VS2017, the button is colored and have only the outer black border, no inner.

UI controls are rendered by the .NET Framework that delegates the rendering to the system (Windows), especially for WinForms that are the historical system GUI.

Else you can use a panel instead and add some behaviors.

Or you can search the web for UI controls and buttons, libre or commercial.

Here is an example of open-source UI controls:

https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton

You can download the GitHub ZIP archive of Krypton and try the KryptonExplorer.exe to see a demo.

The Krypton Toolkit DLL contains a button and you should find what you need.

This library contains lots of good controls, but I never had the time to use it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your assistance with both of my posts. It's my turn to head of bed now. Thanks again